# -webkit-text-fill-color does not work on Chrome 69.0.3

Tags: css, google-chrome

I got a working linear-gradient on a text before. And then I updated Google Chrome to latest version. And I realized the text color is not displaying the background color. (See below)

`background: -webkit-linear-gradient(261deg, #42b551,#42b551, #32597d, #32597d);
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;`

Comment: Same thing happened with me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502824/css-issue-with-webkit-text-fill-color-in-latest-chrome

Comment: have you found the work around? @Valay

Answer (score 0):

[-webkit-text-fill-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color)

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: do you know any alternative?