# css - issue with webkit-text-fill-color in latest chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Please find this https://jsfiddle.net/91famhuv/8/

I am using `webkit-text-fill-color` and `webkit-gradient` to give progressive gradient effect to the description text.
The actually code has a button "Show more" and  by clicking on that button full description will be visible. Initially, only few lines will be visible with gradient effect.

Now, this was working properly before updating `google chrome` to latest version. After updating the chrome, the initial description text does not appear. I can select the text with mouse but it's not visible.

**Even in fiddle, you can select the text next to "Description" with mouse which is not visible by default.**

**Is there an issue with latest `google chrome` or with `webkit-text-fill-color` ? And how to resolve this ?**

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MDN web docs : [-webkit-text-fill-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color)

> **Non-standard** 
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it
>   will not work for every user. There may also be large
>   incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change
>   in the future.

If you found any alternative, i'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

I also think there maybe a bug in the latest version of Chrome as the same rules you are using no longer work for me on buttons, but do on any other elements.

To resolve your issue though, you can change the rule:

```
    .description .info-cell {
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#242424));
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
```

To simply:

```
    .description-text {
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#242424));
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
```

Changing this in your own JSFiddle worked for me, so this is a workaround whilst this bug exists.

Answer (score -3):

To resolve this issue use the below CSS property:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```